# Imgur API Too many requests (bug?)

Tags: imgur

I have an application that uses the imgur api to create images. As of Jan 31 it is failing. I have not made any updates to the application since may and the api has been working fine for over a year prior to this.

When I check `GET https://api.imgur.com/3/credits` all my remaining values are very high

```
{
  "data": {
    "UserLimit": 500,
    "UserRemaining": 500,
    "UserReset": 1612190503,
    "ClientLimit": 12500,
    "ClientRemaining": 12378
  },
  "success": true,
  "status": 200
}
```

but when I try to `POST https://api.imgur.com/3/image` I get a 429 with response body

```
{
  "data": {
    "error": "Imgur is temporarily over capacity. Please try again later."
  },
  "success": false,
  "status": 403
}
```

I thought maybe I had hit my limit for the month of January so I waited but it's still not working. I was able to get the POST to work in postman by not including the referer header and the response headers included

```
"X-Post-Rate-Limit-Limit": "1250",
"X-Post-Rate-Limit-Remaining: "1250"
"X-Post-Rate-Limit-Reset": "-2"
```

Like I said I haven't made any changes to the app in a very long time so not sure what has changed.